# Specific Search results

Tags: ios, uitableview, search

I am using a search bar that I downloaded from [this tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/how-to-add-search-bar-uitableview).

It returns very general results when you click on a certain cell. Ex. if you click on eggs benedict it will go to a view controller that says eggs benedict. I would like to have a specific button on each search result. I believe the problem is the "SELF CONTAINS" in the code below.

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
 {
 NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate 
                                predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",
                                searchText];

searchResults = [recipes filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by, "have a specific button on each search result"?

Comment: When the user searches for an item they will click on the item and i want there to be a different button in the results page so i can link to each search term to view controller specific for each search result.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand what you're trying to do -- this, "link to each search term to view controller specific for each search result" makes no sense to me.

Comment: Ok you know on most online search and display tutorials you will search for an item, click on that item, then it will show up in a view controller as the label that you clicked on. I want to make it so when you search for an item, click on it, it will show a button which you can click on to link to a view controller and not just show up as the label that you clicked on. Please if you have any other questions don't be afraid to ask them.

Comment: I'm not sure why you want that button -- when you click on the search result itself (in a table view row), you can cause the app to transition to whatever controller you want based on the content of that result. It only show "the label that you clicked on" if that's what you tell it to do. You need some kind of logic to determine what search result was selected, and use that to decide which controller to go to next.

Comment: Ok, do you know of a tutorial where I can find how to link it to a specific view controller? Or maybe you could provide me with some code to get me started. Thanks.